# Can not find the "Start" button in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am learning c#, and just installed Visual studio 2019 community edition and have written the **Hello world** program but I don't see **start** button to run it, How do I enable it? There is an attach button instead , am I missing something here?

[image]

[image]

This is weird but I chose a console app of template VBScript and was able to see the start button then created a new project with c# template and now can see the start button in this project as well.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/run-program?view=vs-2019

Comment: To the right of the attach button is a down arrow. Try that to see if you can change it to Start instead of "Attach to Process".

Comment: Hello @OneCricketeer/ @crashmstr ctrl+F5 does nothing.  There is no other option apart from Attach in dropdown

Comment: Are you sure you created the correct project template? in your case, it should be Console application (be it, dotnet framework/donet core) or you created a class library and added the main method just like java programs may do?

Comment: Right click on the toolbar sections and try to ensure the "Debug" cmd/toolbar item is selected/checked and see if you can get the Play icons for debugging options to run. Pressing F5 should also do the same, unless it prompts any setting or error. let us know what you get when you press F5

Comment: @Ak777, Debug is selected, see the screenshot.

Comment: So i think the issue was, you created a VB console template but added a c# class file to it.. huh?

Comment: @Ak777, in 2019 version when you choose a template it already creates a hello world sample program and open it for you in editor, the problem was the missing button, I did not add or remove anything like files or configuration. I wanted to created a C# console app but because of missing button I created VB console app and everything got fixed for both type (template) of app.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you only opened a single file. You need an entire project/Solution to run your code. There are many different types. Try using File/New/Project and create a Console Application. Then you have everything you need, including a Program.cs file.

The green Attach button will then be named differently like `ConsoleApp1` which will then start your program